# Replace boost::timed_wait() with std in c++17

Tags: c++11, boost, mutex, wait, condition-variable

I have a condition variable `std::condition_variable my_cond;`

I want to be able to replace `boost::timed_wait()` with an std equivalent one.

If the previously mentioned condition variable was a boost one, then I would use the boost version of `timed_wait()` like this:
`cond_.timed_wait(lock,timeout);`

where `lock` is `std::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);`
and timeout is a time that is performed with `boost::chrono`.

`boost:chrono`, `boost locks` and `boost mutexes` have been replaced with their std analogues. I have yet to find an alternative to `timed_wait()`.

I try to find a function belonging to std, where it receives the lock as the first parameter and an `std::chrono` type time as a second parameter.
Looking at the documentation of the `condition_variable::wait` here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

I don't see an overloaded wait function where the second argument is a time type.

Is this conversion from `boost::timed_wait()` to `std::wait()` possible?

**EDIT:**
After trying users' Tony Salimi and Howard Hinnant suggestions, unofrtunately i get an error message. This is the error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
std::condition_variable::wait_for(std::scoped_lock<std::mutex>&, const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >&)’
```

This is the line that the error is given:

```
if(!my_cond.wait_for(lock,timeout))
```

`timeout` is: `auto const timeout = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds( ms );`

`lock` is: `std::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);` where `mutex_` is `mutable std::mutex mutex_;`

Comment: Why not using the `wait_for` method, [documented here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for)?

Comment: @TonySalimi Thanks! I tried this, but I get an error. I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 2):

For `boost` `condition_variable::timed_wait` is overloaded on waiting for a time *duration*, and waiting until a time *point*.  And it isn't clear which overload you are using.

In `std` these functions have slightly different names instead of being overloaded on the same name:

- Waiting for a time duration maps to `wait_for`.
- Waiting until a time point maps to `wait_until`.

See the "see also" section of the page you linked to:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

For `wait_for` you can use any `std::chrono::duration` instantiation (`duration` is a class template).  Common examples are `std::chrono::milliseconds` and `std::chrono::seconds`.

For `wait_until` you can use any `std::chrono::time_point` instantiation for which [`std::chrono::time_point::clock` meets the Cpp17Clock requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread#req.paramname-1.sentence-6).  Common examples are `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` and `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

### Update

[`std::condition_variable` waits on a `std::unique_lock`, not a `std::scoped_lock`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for)

The history of the names of the locks is a bit tortured.

Originally there was `boost::scoped_lock`.  During the standardization process, functionality changed, and so did the names.  `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` were introduced in C++11.  Neither was identical to `boost::scoped_lock`, and the different names helped imply that.

Then in C++17, `std::scoped_lock` was introduced which added new functionality, and is even more different from `boost::scoped_lock`.

`std::unique_lock` is the lock used for all `condition_variable` operations.  It alone has the semantics that it can hold ownership in a non-scoped manner.  That is, it has `unlock()`.  This is consistent with the semantics of `condition_variable::wait` which unlocks the lock upon waiting, and re-locks it when returning from the wait.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this approach but I get an error. I updated the question with the error.

Comment: Updated answer to address your error message.

Comment: Thank you! I used `scoped_lock`, because that's what the original boost code was using.  Therefore I converted `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);` to `std::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);` If i use a `unique_lock`, will the functionality remain the same (given that there was a `scoped_lock` previously)? Also, I have to note that I get the same error on the `wait()` function, with a scoped lock parameter inside (`this->cond_.wait( lock );`)